# JavaScript cookies showing different nature

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to build up a small model of a shopping cart. It will work perfectly when I add some items to my cart and it shows the items in the check out time. But  when I try after clearing all the browser history and cookies, it will not work for sometime. But some time I will work suddenly. I am not able to find out the reason.

Please take a look at the url http://synergiadigital.com/restaurant2/orderFood.php

Thanks in advance,

Sunil

Comment: You're open to SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks for your time , How can I solve it .. Please replay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maby you are leaving the last Tab opened when deleting all browser data, then if you click on a submit button for example you cretae the deleted cookie again, this could explain why its working sometimes after deleting browser data.

Comment: Thanks for the time . But my problem is showing only after clearing all the browser history and cookie. After clearing all , it will not work perfectly, but some times, it will wok :(